# subanalytic realization of smooth abstract stratification

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, embeddings, stratifications

Consider an $C^\infty$ abstract stratification $A$ (in the Thom-Mather sense, see Mather's note).

---

Can we embed $A$ in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or in an analytic manifold) as a subanalytic set?

If not, what could be the problem?

---

This apparently was shown by Laurent Noirel in his thesis for the $C^k$ case, $1 \leq k < \infty$.